# How to put the list-item overlapping the form groups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day everyone, I want my search results to show on top of school association so that my form won't be broken, I want it to overlap the school association form-groups

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work so we can help you.

Comment: @Soviut, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I wonder if someone can send a response on this ?

Comment: You need to show some code otherwise we can't tell you what you need to do. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, it's a Q&A site.